# Can not get data from rowsInserted signal

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm using Python 3.4.3 and PyQt 5.4.2 and have some problems, when trying to get data from rowsInserted signal.

I want to get data from all items near the dropped item after drop operation.

Here some of my code (whole model class is too large, hope this part is enough):

```
class PlModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rowsInserted.connect(self.printSomeData)

    def supportedDragActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction

    def canDropMimeData(self, QMimeData, Qt_DropAction, p_int, p_int_1, QModelIndex):
        if not self.itemFromIndex(QModelIndex) and p_int_1 == p_int == -1:
            return False
        elif QModelIndex.isValid():
            if self.item(self.itemFromIndex(QModelIndex).row(), 0) is None:
                return False
            else:
                return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.canDropMimeData(self, QMimeData, Qt_DropAction, p_int, p_int_1, QModelIndex)
        else:
            return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.canDropMimeData(self, QMimeData, Qt_DropAction, p_int, p_int_1, QModelIndex)

    def dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, row, col, modelindex):
        if not self.itemFromIndex(modelindex):
            if row == col == -1:
                return False    
            else:
                return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, row, 0, self.index(row, 0))
        elif self.itemFromIndex(modelindex).isDragEnabled():
            if row == col == -1:
                crow = self.item(modelindex.row(), 0).rowCount()
                return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, crow, 0, self.indexFromItem(self.item(modelindex.row(), 0)))
            else:
                return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, row, 0, modelindex)
        elif self.itemFromIndex(modelindex).isDropEnabled():
            if col != -1:
                return False
            else:
                return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, row, 0, modelindex)
        else:
            return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, row, 0, modelindex)

    def printSomeData(self, ind: QtCore.QModelIndex, first, last):
        row = ind.row()
        item = self.itemFromIndex(ind)
        for i in range(0, item.rowCount()):
            print(self.index(i, 0, ind).data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole))
```

This code prints valid data for all items, excluding dropped item. For dropped item it prints 'None'. After dropping in QTreeView all data is OK. What wrong with it?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: How does the drop operation work ? It would help to have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @tmoreau I tried to extend my code example. Unfortunately, model class is too large and depens on some other parts of my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like rowsInserted signal emits after rows were inserted, but before model fills data in inserted rows.
So I call printSomeData function from dropMimeData function (after data was dropped) and it works.

Here corrected code:

```
class PlModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QStandardItemModel.__init__(self)
        # no need for connect
        #self.rowsInserted.connect(self.printSomeData)

    def supportedDragActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction

    def canDropMimeData(self, QMimeData, Qt_DropAction, p_int, p_int_1, QModelIndex):
        if not self.itemFromIndex(QModelIndex) and p_int_1 == p_int == -1:
            return False
        elif QModelIndex.isValid():
            if self.item(self.itemFromIndex(QModelIndex).row(), 0) is None:
                return False
            else:
                return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.canDropMimeData(self, QMimeData, Qt_DropAction, p_int, p_int_1, QModelIndex)
        else:
            return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.canDropMimeData(self, QMimeData, Qt_DropAction, p_int, p_int_1, QModelIndex)

    def dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, row, col, modelindex):
        if not self.itemFromIndex(modelindex):
            if row == col == -1:
                return False    
            else:
                result = QtGui.QStandardItemModel.dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, row, 0, self.index(row, 0))
                if result:
                    self.printSomeData(self.index(row, 0))
                return result
        elif self.itemFromIndex(modelindex).isDragEnabled():
            if row == col == -1:
                crow = self.item(modelindex.row(), 0).rowCount()
                result = QtGui.QStandardItemModel.dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, crow, 0, self.indexFromItem(self.item(modelindex.row(), 0)))
                if result:
                    self.printSomeData(self.indexFromItem(self.item(modelindex.row(), 0)))
                return result
            else:
                result = QtGui.QStandardItemModel.dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, row, 0, modelindex)
                if result:
                    self.printSomeData(modelindex)
                return result
        elif self.itemFromIndex(modelindex).isDropEnabled():
            if col != -1:
                return False
            else:
                result = QtGui.QStandardItemModel.dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, row, 0, modelindex)
                if result:
                    self.printSomeData(modelindex)
                return result
        else:
            result = QtGui.QStandardItemModel.dropMimeData(self, mimedata, dropaction, row, 0, modelindex)
                if result:
                    self.printSomeData(modelindex)
                return result

    def printSomeData(self, ind: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        row = ind.row()
        item = self.itemFromIndex(ind)
        for i in range(0, item.rowCount()):
            print(self.index(i, 0, ind).data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole))
```